# Adding events to google calendar in yii2

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

how to add events to google calendar in yii2 ? I used google api client library, but it is not working in yii2.

This is the code i used.

```
 // Get the API client and construct the service object.

$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
        'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
        'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
        'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
'start' => array(
'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
),
'end' => array(
'dateTime' => '2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
),
'recurrence' => array(
'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
),
'attendees' => array(
array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
),
'reminders' => array(
'useDefault' => FALSE,
'overrides' => array(
  array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
  array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
  ),
),
));

$calendarId = 'primary';
$event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
```

Comment: any calendar or google calendar is required ?

Comment: I need google calendar

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I have posted the code.